# Declaring number of variable based on the value of a variable

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to compare `n` numbers to see which one is the minimum value. `n` is a value from a cell

```
n = Sheet1.Range("C6").Value
```

So if `n` is equal to `2` then I have to declare two variables and use `min` function. The data will be arranged in two different columns as shown below. I would have no idea where the data ends down.

```
 1    2 
 3    4 
 '    '
 '    '
```

I want to use array to declare the variables based on n and with the loop but I don't know how and I am not familiar with array in VBA. I am open to all solutions. You don't have to use array but that is one of the way I thought of using. Currently, I have only done it by getting the two values which I have already declared. I need to use the loop to get two different values for every row to compare and find the minimum value. There are no error with my codes.

```
x = 1
Do Until IsEmpty(Sheet9.Cells(x, 30).Value)
    no2 = Sheet9.Cells(x, 30).Value
    no1 = Sheet9.Cells(x, 31).Value
    result = WorksheetFunction.Min(no1, no2)
    Sheet9.Cells(x, 30).Value = result
    x = x + 1
Loop
```

Comment: So what is your actual question? You didn't ask one. Please also describe what your code does and what you expect it to do, and if there are any errors. [Edit] your question to add these information.

Comment: you can declare an array and based on the variable n you can loop to get the values into the array and then use worksheetfunction min to get the minimum values of the array. you can also sort the array and then get the first value.

Comment: would the formula `=max(col 30,col 31)` filled down not suffice?

Comment: @SivaprasathV mind showing an example ? Thanks

Comment: `=MIN(OFFSET($B1,0,0,1,$A1))` filled down??  Where B is the start of the data and A is where `n` would be

Comment: @RachelChia There is still no question in your text. And it's still very unclear to me what your goal is. Be as *specific* as possible in asking your question. Read [ask] for help.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question, you just need to add one more condition in the Do Until Loop like this...

```
X = 1
Do Until IsEmpty(Sheet9.Cells(X, 30).Value) Or X > Sheet1.Range("C6").Value
    no2 = Sheet9.Cells(X, 30).Value
    no1 = Sheet9.Cells(X, 31).Value
    result = WorksheetFunction.Min(no1, no2)
    Sheet9.Cells(X, 30).Value = result
    X = X + 1
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Let the Cell containing the Number of values to consider be 'C6'.

If you have a value of 3 in 'C6' then you have find the minimum of the cells 'A30:A32' and paste the value in 'A30' this is what i have understood from your question.

```
Sub Minarr()
dim nos() as integer

n=int(sheet1.range('C6').value)
set cell=Sheet9.cells(1,30)
if not isempty(cell) then
for i=0 to n
nos[i]=cell.offset(i,0).value
next i
result=Application.worksheetfunction.min(nos)
cell.value=result
end if
end sub
```